# After a pointer has been declared and initialized, when do you prefix the variable literal with asterisk and when not?

Tags: c++, c

Does the plain literal refer to the address and *literal refer to the actual value at the address? So, AFTER:

```
int i = 0;
int *iPointer = &i;
```

the following expression will lookup the VALUE AT memory address &i:

```
*iPointer
```

and the following will simply yield the memory address &i:

```
iPointer
```

I stepped through and verified my hypothesis, but I want to make sure (you never know with these things).

I guess I'm just confused by the * symbol's different purposes in declaration and access.

Comment: In C++ you often see the declaration written as `int*   p;` to stress that the type of `p` is `int*`. Not that often in C.

Comment: Declaration reflects use.  `*` is the dereference operator, so `*` declares pointers.  `[]` is the array access operator, so `[]` declares arrays.  `()` is the function call syntax, so `()` declares functions.

Comment: @ecat Yeah... except `int a[10]` declares an array of ten integers, but the expression `a[10]` invokes undefined behavior :) Also, `int &ref` declares a reference to an integer, but the expression `&ref` is a pointer to an integer :)

Comment: You gotta love C, where something like `v = *i***p` makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely correct.

Also, note that `&` can also declare a reference, depending on context.

**In a declaration**, `*` declares a pointer type.

**When applied** on a pointer (like `*ptr`), it represents the **dereference operator** and returns the value the pointer points to.

Note that `operator *` can be overloaded, so you can also apply it to objects, not only pointers, and have it do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration mimics use.

If you have a pointer `p` that points to an integer value, you access that integer value by dereferencing `p` with the unary `*` operator, as in

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so the declaration of `p` is

```
int *p;
```

The type of the *variable* `p` is "pointer to `int`", or `int *`.  However, the declaration is written such that the type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`.

Thus, any time you want to access the integer value pointed to by `p`, you must use `*p`.  If all you care about is the address value contained in `p`, you just use `p`.  For example, dereferencing a NULL pointer leads to undefined behavior, so you at least want to check that the pointer value isn't NULL before attempting to dereference it:

```
if (p != NULL)
  x = *p;
```

In the condition, we're concerned with the value contained in `p`, so we don't dereference it.  In the statement, we're concerned with the value `p` *points to*, so we dereference it there.

Note that the declaration

```
int* p, q;
```

is the same as

```
int *p;
int q;
```

in that only `p` is declared as a pointer; `q` is declared as a regular `int`.